# rpm spec to only install certain files based on system criteria

Tags: bash, sh, rpm, specifications

I have an RPM I build which unpacks a bunch of scripts I use across three different types of systems.  I am trying to add a fourth system type which only needs a subset of the files packaged in the rpm.  Is there a way to have the %install section only install some of the payload based on a simple check. something like

(sudo code)

```
if systemtype eq "type4"; then
    install %file4
else
    install %file
fi
```

All four systems run the same OS and a single RPM makes it much easier for me to give the RPM to other people for them to use, so I'd love to get this done with a single package.

I know I can do this in the %post section but the list of file I'll need to delete is very long, so I'd like to avoid this if I can.

Comment: aren't rpm install scripts pretty much just shell scripts? you could simply list all the to-be-installed files in a file, then `install \`cat filelist\`` or whatever the rpm script equivalent is.

Answer (score 1):

Completing this task with a single RPM isn't a very good plan. As Marc said you can write a shell script like you would anywhere else, but based on your question this seems irrational. In your question you explained that this RPM goes onto one machine, so why not just package an RPM for that specific system? This reduces the RPM complexity in the event other users need to maintain the RPM, and it reduces the bloat on the RPM as well. In the short term a single RPM may be easier but in the long run multiple RPMs are going to be the better solution.

Comment: I agree that one RPM is not a good solution, but instead of using different RPM for the fourth system, which leads to code duplication, you can make a 'base' RPM with files common to all, and another package with the extra files which depends on the base package.

Comment: @Eran, that is another possibility, but the issue there is then there are three RPMs (the base, the package for type 1 machines, and the package for type 2 machines) as opposed to two RPMs. It might also be confusing for others when it's explained that they have to install this base package, then one of two packages depending on machine type.

Comment: Fortunately, we have YUM. Build a YUM DB, and do all your installs with YUM. It's very easy to deploy, and solve all these problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your spec file emit more than one RPM file at once. This is called ["subpackaging"](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-subpack.html).

If you adjust them so that they match the dependencies given on the various machines, you  could end up with a certain number of packages which can be installed as they are fit.

Comment: Subpackaging now at: https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/rpm/max-rpm/ch-rpm-subpack.html